# Oversaturated colors in Chrome (V43) on wide gamut monitor

Tags: color-management, srgb, wide-gamut

I recently bought my first wide gamut monitor (Eizo CS420) and calibrated it using a Spyder4Pro. Everything appears to be working great in Lightroom and Photoshop, and I can finally appreciate the difference between sRGB and ProPhotoRGB, for example.

However, Chrome (43.0.2357.65) appears to ignore my monitor's profile - all pictures/color elements are wildly oversaturated, regardless of whether I've exported them from LR with sRGB, AdobeRGB or ProPhotoRGB.

When I do the [Web browser color management test](http://cameratico.com/tools/web-browser-color-management-test/), there is no difference between sRGB and ProPhotoRGB - both color bars are at maximum saturation.

[image: Chrome color bars]

In Firefox, only the ProPhotoRGB bars are fully saturated, the sRGB bars look more subdued (as expected - it's about what fully saturated bars look like on my old monitor). I guess when you're watching the images in this question on a correctly calibrated monitor, they will look dull...

[image: Firefox color bars]

To summarize, it appears to me that Chrome does interpret embedded ICC profiles from images, but it outputs them as if targeting an sRGB display. Am I wrong about this? Could I have setup my monitor incorrectly (if so, where would I need to check this?) Or is this Chrome's fault? Can I do anything about this?

Comment: This is a problem across browsers and other programs, even more so in mobile, they take the RGB values and use the full range of the device screen. Using something different than sRGB risks showing yellows as yellow-greens in some screens.In Mac, Chrome used not to respect ICC, more recent version seems to respect it.

Comment: Well, it appears that at least Firefox handles it correctly - Internet Explorer 11 has the same problem as Chrome. Windows' own Photo Viewer displays the pictures correctly (although the thumbnails in Windows Explorer *are* oversaturated). This is annoying...

Comment: This question is about browser behavior, not photography.

Comment: You're right, but the problem is of concern to photographers who publish their pictures on the web. I suspect there are a few of those around here who might have some experience with this problem. Also, I wasn't sure whether I might have set up my equipment incorrectly and it only looks like a browser problem to me...

Comment: ... plus it's unlikely that attendants of stackoverflow , even when fond of browsers, would know anything about this topic (if they know about color space at all), while it's a hot concern in photography. You might try in Computer Graphics echange, though (but it is not very active).

Comment: More like a question for SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a good analysis of the issue here: http://www.color-management-guide.com/web-browser-color-management.html

Answer (score 2):

Here you can also test, which ICC version your browser supports: http://cameratico.com/tools/web-browser-color-management-test/

On Mac only Safari supports v2 and v4. Also it's rendering CSS values correctly/not completely oversaturated. But this is also described in the article provided by Andrew Sharpe in the other answer.