# How to calibrate my monitors and colorspaces to to best create a workflow or editing raw photos for uploading and viewing on the web

Tags: color-management, color-spaces, rgb, adobe-rgb, prophoto

Question 1:
I have bought 2 monitors-4K ADOBE RGB and 4K SRGB. What/how should I set up the monitors' calibrations and color spaces to best edit my raw photos for exporting to the web?

Question 2:
I am concerned that the uploaded web photos will look worse to the end-viewer if I edit on my monitor in ADOBE or prophoto color space.
Does editing in a prophoto RGB or ADOBE RGB workspace make the exported/converted sRGB web photos look worse?

Question 3: Should I return my expensive Dell Adobe RGB monitor? I am not doing prints.

Comment: We need to know whether you're on Mac or Win. You start by buying a hardware colorimeter. You're not calibrating to a specific RGB profile, that's handled by your OS & Photoshop etc. (On the road this week. Proper answer when I get back, if no-one beats me to it. )

Comment: Related: [What are the merits of a wide-gamut display in post-processing for web?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20197/15871) and [Oversaturated colors in Chrome (V43) on wide gamut monitor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/63907/15871) and [How to do batch conversion from Adobe RGB to Srgb](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86701/15871)

Comment: You can use your camera to calibrate your monitor by setting WB to cloudy (6500), taking shots of test patterns, then using the eyedropper tool to see how far off the monitor is. Adjust, repeat until all RGB levels on a B+W step wedge match or come as close as possible to matching; then your monitor is calibrated for 6500.

Answer (score 1):

You should be editing in the sRGB document color space, and exporting/saving the images with that color space embedded. Therefore, the color space capability of the monitor beyond sRGB isn't really relevant.

However, a monitor that is "sRGB" does not mean it has *only* sRGB colors, nor that it has all of them. So a monitor that is capable of more colors, and all of sRGB, may be better.

Editing in a color space with colors that your monitor cannot display (e.g. ProPhoto) means you are making edits you cannot see... you can do that, but you would want to softproof your image in sRGB before saving it as an sRGB jpeg/png... if your monitor is only capable of sRGB (or less than), you are already "softproofing" in effect. And likewise for editing in a larger color space you can see (e.g.  Adobe RGB (1998) on an  Adobe RGB (1998) capable monitor). You might want to work in a larger color space if you are saving the working document (layered tiff/psd/etc) in order to retain as much original color data as possible; for some possible future use... i.e. advancements in display/print technology.

And then, for your own benefit you want to calibrate both monitors to be as accurate as possible, while looking as similar as possible... tradeoffs will probably have to be made.

But in the end, you have no control as to how the image will be viewed on the web... so all of this concern and effort on your end is largely wasted.

Comment: *(e.g. adobe on an adobe capable monitor)* - do you mean Adobe RGB (1998)?

Comment: @MrUpsidown, yes.